# Where can I download an earlier version of iOS for backwards compatibility testing?

Tags: iphone, testing, ios

Does anyone know where I can download iOS version 3.1.3?

I've been searching on [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) but haven't been able to find anything.
I know that it is possible to install earlier versions of iOS using organiser (I believe the file extension for the iOS images is ipsw)

Comment: I don't believe Apple maintains an archive of old versions.  I'm sure I'm not the only developer hoarding them on external hard drives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you can at least download them from Apple, though I'm having trouble installing. I believe each piece of hardware has it's own build. Here's a [link](http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone/061-7468.20100202.pbnrt/iPhone1,2_3.1.3_7E18_Restore.ipsw) for 3.1.3 for a 3G iPhone.

More generally, iClarified has a [list](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=750) for all firmware updates. Why this list isn't on apple.com in an obvious place utterly eludes me.

Answer (score 1):

Also found you can download them here - http://www.downloadios.net

Though installing them is another question - [Downgrading iOS / Upgrading to version not the most recent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861482/downgrading-ios-upgrading-to-version-not-the-most-recent)

Comment: Yes you're right - I believe during a restore, Apple needs to create a digital signature based on a combination of the iOS image file (IPSW), and your device ID. The signing server will stop working for older iOS versions once a newer one is released. The workaround is to save these digital signitures (known in the jailbreaking community as SHSH blobs) in advance, but if you don't have them you're stuck.